# Image added to Appbar not showing - flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

I have added an image to my appbar but it does not show when I run the app. Here is my code:

```
       appBar: AppBar(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset('assets/images/Appbar_logo.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 56),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Here is the error:

> Unable to load asset: assets/Appbar_logo.png

Here is the package structure in the project:

```
Project
   lib
      assets.images
         Appbar_logo.png
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
 assets:
    - images/
```

I think there is an issue with my package layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your assets folder is inside the lib ? It should be on roots
Project

- android
- assets
- ios
- lib
- test
  ...

And in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
    flutter:
      assets: 
      - assets/images/Appbar_logo.png
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the changes you suggested but it still didn't work. I now have:project -> assets-> images->Appbar_logo.png. In the pubspec.yaml I have the same line you suggested.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

try including assets folder in the path in your pubspec.yaml file

```
 assets:
    - assets/images/
```